# How to convert string to integer from json response in reactjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs

[How to convert string to int from json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPSd4.png)

```
     if(this.state.chartCategory == 'D3Chart'){
      console.log("chartdata for d3 charts", this.state.d3line.chartData);
      var a = parseInt(this.state.d3line.chartData)
      console.log("a", a);
        switch(this.state.chartType){
          case 'area': return <div  style={{width: 900, height:300}}><Areagraph  data = {this.state.d3line.chartData} vars = {{x: this.state.d3line.x, y: this.state.d3line.y}} dispatch = {this.showFilter} title = {this.state.data.chartName}/></div>;
          case 'pie': return  <div style={{width: 900, height:500}}><Piegraph  data = {this.state.d3line.chartData} vars = {{x: this.state.d3line.x, y: this.state.d3line.y}} dispatch = {this.showFilter} title = {this.state.data.chartName}/></div>;
          case 'bar': return  <div  style={{width: 900, height:300}}><Bargraph  data = {this.state.d3line.chartData} vars = {{x: this.state.d3line.x, y: this.state.d3line.y}} dispatch = {this.showFilter} title = {this.state.data.chartName}/></div>;
          case 'line' : return <div  style={{width: 900, height:300}}><Linegraph  data = {this.state.d3line.chartData} vars = {{x:this.state.d3line.x, y: this.state.d3line.y, group: this.state.d3line.x}} dispatch = {this.showFilter} title = {this.state.data.chartName}/></div>;
          default: return null;
       }   

    }
```

I am getting a as NAN i want to check if the value is integer convert string to integer else it should remains same

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where exactly in your code do you want to convert what value?

Comment: Please, could you clarify your question? Can you show us some example that you have tried?

Comment: `var a = parseInt(this.state.d3line.chartData)` you cannot parse a complex object straight to a single integer, that's why you're getting `NaN`

Comment: Please add exactly what do you want to convert. Please show exactly what data is returned by "this.state.d3line.chartData"

Comment: also, please do not post pictures of code or results, just add them as snippets in your questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string to integer in reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47469354/convert-string-to-integer-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i *think* this is what you are after.

(Admittedly there a prettier ways to do this in ES6)

```
if(this.state.chartCategory == 'D3Chart'){

    //convert all UNIT_PRICE values in this.state.d3line.chartData to number
    for(var i=0; i < this.state.d3line.chartData.length; i++)
    {
        this.state.d3line.chartData[i].UNIT_PRICE = parseInt(this.state.d3line.chartData[i].UNIT_PRICE);
    }

    switch(this.state.chartType){
      case 'area': return <div  style={{width: 900, height:300}}><Areagraph  data = {this.state.d3line.chartData} vars = {{x: this.state.d3line.x, y: this.state.d3line.y}} dispatch = {this.showFilter} title = {this.state.data.chartName}/></div>;
      case 'pie': return  <div style={{width: 900, height:500}}><Piegraph  data = {this.state.d3line.chartData} vars = {{x: this.state.d3line.x, y: this.state.d3line.y}} dispatch = {this.showFilter} title = {this.state.data.chartName}/></div>;
      case 'bar': return  <div  style={{width: 900, height:300}}><Bargraph  data = {this.state.d3line.chartData} vars = {{x: this.state.d3line.x, y: this.state.d3line.y}} dispatch = {this.showFilter} title = {this.state.data.chartName}/></div>;
      /*case 'column': return  <div className = "graphContainer" style={{width: 900, height:300, overflow: "hidden", resize: "both", paddingBottom: "10px", border: "1px solid black"}}><Columngraph  data = {this.state.d3line.chartData} vars = {{x: this.state.d3line.x, y: this.state.d3line.y}} dispatch = {this.showFilter} title = {this.state.data.chartName}/></div>;*/
      case 'line' : return <div  style={{width: 900, height:300}}><Linegraph  data = {this.state.d3line.chartData} vars = {{x:this.state.d3line.x, y: this.state.d3line.y, group: this.state.d3line.x}} dispatch = {this.showFilter} title = {this.state.data.chartName}/></div>;
      default: return null;
   }   

}
```

Comment: instead of unit price if i put this.state.d3line.y showing state error